# How to get correct name to appear in console? Java

Tags: java, enums, abstract-class

I am having trouble finishing this problem. I cannot get the console to print the names in the problem. This is a program that creates a roshambo game.

Here is my code.

```
public enum Roshambo {

    rock {
        public String toString() {
            return "rock";
        }
    },
    paper {
        public String toString() {
            return "paper";
        }
    },
    scissors {
        public String toString() {
            return "scissors";
        }
    } 
}

public abstract class Player {

    String name;
    Roshambo value;

    abstract Roshambo generateRoshambo();

    void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    void setRoshambo(Roshambo value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    Roshambo getRoshambo() {
        return value;
    } 
}

class Bart extends Player {
    public Roshambo generateRoshambo() {
        super.name = "Bart";
        return Roshambo.rock;
    } 
}


public class Lisa extends Player {
    public Roshambo generateRoshambo() {
        super.name = "Lisa";
        Random r = new Random();
        int ch = r.nextInt(3);
        if (ch == 0) return Roshambo.rock;
        else if (ch == 1) return Roshambo.paper;
        else return Roshambo.scissors;
    } 
}

public class Player1 extends Player {

    char value;

    Player1(char value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Roshambo generateRoshambo() {
        if (value == 'r')
            return Roshambo.rock;
        else if (value == 's')
            return Roshambo.scissors;
        else
            return Roshambo.paper;
    } 
}

import java.util.Scanner;

public class RoshamboApp {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        char choice = 'y';
        char player;

        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Welcome to the game of Roshambo");

        Bart b = new Bart();
        Lisa l = new Lisa();
        Player p = null;

        String name;
        System.out.println("Enter your name : ");
        name = s.next();

        System.out.println("Would you like to play Bart or Lisa?(B/L):");
        player = s.next().charAt(0);

        if (player == 'b')
            p = b;

        else if (player == 'l')
            p = l;

        while (choice != 'n') {
            System.out.println("Rock, paper or scissors?(R/P/S)");
            char ch = s.next().charAt(0);
            Player1 p1 = new Player1(ch);
            System.out.println(name + ":" + p1.generateRoshambo());
            System.out.println(player + ":" + p.generateRoshambo());

            if (p1.generateRoshambo() == p.generateRoshambo())
                System.out.println("Draw!");

            else if (p1.generateRoshambo() == Roshambo.paper && p.generateRoshambo() == Roshambo.rock)
                System.out.println(p1.getName() + "Wins");

            else if (p1.generateRoshambo() == Roshambo.paper && p.generateRoshambo() == Roshambo.scissors)
                System.out.println(p.getName() + "Wins!");

            else if (p1.generateRoshambo() == Roshambo.scissors && p.generateRoshambo() == Roshambo.rock)
                System.out.println(p.getName() + "Wins");

            System.out.println("Play again?(y/n):");
            choice = s.next().charAt(0);
        }
    } 
}
```

The console prints out like this:

Welcome to the game of Roshambo
Enter your name : 
sean
Would you like to play Bart or Lisa?(B/L):
b
Rock, paper or scissors?(R/P/S)
paper
sean:paper
b:rock
nullWins
Play again?(y/n):

I am trying to get the b:rock to become Bart: rock and null wins to become sean wins.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is overly complicated code around, like here:

```
public enum Roshambo {
 ROCK("rock"), ... other constants  ;

 private final String stringRepresentation;
 private Roshambo(String stringRepresentation) {
  this.stringRepresentation = stringRepresentation;
 }

 @Override
 public String toString() { return stringRepresentation; }
```

for example.

Regarding your actual problem in main: your Player1 class again is 10 times more complicated than required. Simply ask the user: "what do you want to play"; and depending on his input, select a Roshambo.

In other words: I would recommend you to

1. Change your Player class to `ComputerPlayer` to indicate that this one is somehow computing a Roshambo value
2. Change your Player1 class into a `UserPlayer` or something alike.

Long story short: your main problem is that you are doing things too complicated. So you can't focus on the problem you try to solve. Another example; you could change the selection of the computer player like

```
char playerSelection = ... coming from user
if (playerSelection == 'b') {
  player = new Bart();
} else {
  player = new Lisa(); 
}
```

Those single-char named variables dont say anything; they just help to confuse what you intend to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is you are printing player, which is just the character of the player they want to play:

```
player = s.next().charAt(0);
 ...

System.out.println(name + ":" + p1.generateRoshambo());
System.out.println(player + ":" + p.generateRoshambo());
```

you should print the players name:

```
System.out.println(p.getName() + ":" + p.generateRoshambo());
```

**Note**

This code is overly complicated, the same task can be done in fewer lines of code and much clearer. Look into refactoring.